# Serial communication over usb raspberry pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

How do I send information from a raspberry pi to an arduino over the USB port in c++? Optimally, I would want sending and receiving serial info to be as easy as

```
Serial.println("food");
Temp = Serial.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Boost::ASIO?

Check an example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html).